# React native using the passing value from onPress function show another component view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

want to update a component view by using the parameter value passed from onPress  function in react native.

Comment: What does your current code look like and what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
    const onItemClick = (item) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));          
     }
    
      const renderItem = ({ index, item }) => (
    
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => {onItemClick(item)} } >
            <Text> {item.name} </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       );
```

Comment: onPress={ () => {onItemClick(item)}

using this to pass data to onPress in FlatList in hooks